# Yarn Link, Changes To Linked Package Not Reflected in Host App

Tags: angular5, yarnpkg, npm-link

I'm learning about using `yarn link` to work on a package and have changes reflected in a host app and I either don't get something or somethings not working.

It is all built in angular5..

I have an app MyApp that contains, among others, `@org/my-package` in `node_modules`.

I need to make changes to my-package and in order to serve the changes I use `yarn link` to create symlink and test the package in MyApp.

This is what I do...

In my-package, I run a build. It creates the distribution files. I then cli into dist package and run `yarn link`.. This is success.. I get the instruction to use `yarn link @org/my-package` in MyApp cli..

Then I go to MyApp, and I run `yarn link @org/my-package`. This is success as well..

However when I make changes in my-package and run a build again, they don't get reflected in MyApp.

What am I not understanding?

I get no errors.

Is `@org/my-package` that is in `node_modules` in MyApp supposed to be there or not? Isn't `yarn link` on the dist in my-package meant to override that one?

No matter how much I search it looks like yarn documentation is a bit light on this topic.

Comment: I had this problem, and it resolved as soon as I restarted webpack-dev-server in my host app. webpack-dev-server loads a module once then caches it, assuming that it won't change. Changing package code requires a restart.

Comment: But can you do it with hot reload? I mean you obviously restart the app, but how to make the hot reload see changes you made in dep package and hot reload the main app?

Comment: @LukeGriffiths suggestion pointed me to the terminal where the project dev server was running - in my case, the app was hanging during the build on a syntax error that had already been fixed in the subsequent build - long story short... the most suggested IT solution worked for me `turn it off, then turn it back on` after that my hot reload kicked back in

Answer (score 5):

I faced similar kind of a issue. But what I did was edit the package.json in the project that depends on the component library to for example "@org/my-package": "link:../packages/dist/my-package" (edit the path) This only works with yarn, if you use npm this is not an option, but you could use npm link.

I had to do a yarn install after that in the project. So, when you re-build my-package, the @org/my-package that is in node_modules in MyApp supposed to be updated.

Answer (score 2):

Delete node_modules and reinstall all the packages and reset `yarn link your_local_package` work fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too.

When I updated my library, it didn't reflect in my main project. I looked inside the modules and there was my package. Everything was fine and up to date, nothing was wrong. That's when I decided to delete the `angular\cache` folder, and it worked. Try this setting inside your **angular.json**. It worked for me:

```
"cli": {
    "cache": {
        "enabled": false
    }
}
```

[For more information on clearing cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69953135/clear-angular-cache-in-angular-folder)