# Clear angular cache in .angular folder

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular-cache

From version `13.0.0` there will be a `.angular` folder generated in root which is ignored by git containing a `cache` folder which caches builds.

How can I remove (or clear) this cache?

Comment: Not 100% relevant to the question, but perhaps still useful for others, I upgraded from Angular 12 to 13 and manually had to add `.angular` to my `.gitignore` - it was not added for me.

Comment: That's weird... Mine added automatically. @fullStackChris

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You can configure caching options of cli in `angular.json` file. One of options is `cache` which gives you the option of disabling it.

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "cli": {
    "cache": {
      "enabled": false
    }
  },
  "projects": {}
}
```

You can disable it by running this command too:

```
ng config cli.cache.enabled false
```

- To clear the cache on Unix-based operating systems:

```
rm -rf .angular/cache
```

- To clear the cache on Windows:

```
rmdir /s /q .angular/cache
```

---

### Update (10th, Aug 2022):

For Angular 14 and up, you can now clear, enable and disable cache config by running these commands:

#### clean

```
ng cache clean

// Deletes persistent disk cache from disk.
```

#### disable

```
ng cache disable
ng cache off

// Disables persistent disk cache for all projects in the workspace.
```

#### enable

```
ng cache enable
ng cache on
```

You can find out more about it in [docs](https://angular.io/cli/cache).

Comment: Deleting the /.Angular/Cache/ directory (like the command "rmdir" is doing) worked for me!  I'm specifically calling out that rmdir deletes the directory, incase anybody glosses over this.

Answer (score 12):

To clear the Angular [cache](https://angular.io/cli/cache) you can run:

```
ng cache clean
```

Comment: This needs Angular >= 14

Comment: Best option, worked for me!