# Ng build keeps import old version of a library

Tags: angular, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I modified an existing library and import in my Angular project with `yarn link` with a different name. Yesterday I still saw changes in the code of the custom library in the project build (I checked the main.js). Today I did not see any changes so I tried several things but none worked,

- Delete the original library
- Unlink, build the custom library, link, and build the project
- Restart Wsl2
- Restart my computer, build again
- Delete the link, create a copy of the custom library in node_module
- Delete node_module, and reinstall, create such copy

When I deleted the custom library from node_module, ng build failed due to unresolved paths, so it is obvious my project did not import code from different library.

Can someone point out what happens here?

Update 2022/11/27

- For a few builds this morning, the code from the library was updated. But after that, it was messed up again. Now, beside some lines of code were not included, some values I changed for from the original library now reappeared themselves.

Answer (score 2):

The culprit is Angular cache. I followed the guide to disable cache, and it works, [Clear angular cache in .angular folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69953135/clear-angular-cache-in-angular-folder)